# WSL for 20.04 Lost mysql? I lost my databases. I can't dump connect start mysql

Tags: server, mysql

I have lost about £300 today as UBUNTU WSL will not let me install/ reinstall mysql on WSL. After i did an upgrade first i had an innodb corruption. So i followed [this](https://chepri.com/mysql-innodb-corruption-and-recovery/) guide and did a backup of database. I forgot to backup my PHP files (My fault). Now a day later after doing some more development the mysql DB is unusable. Will never get it back and I am at the point of never using WSL ever again. I am having to roll back to last weeks work if that backup even works.

I have tried to reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo service mysql start
sudo mysql -u root
```

I have tried everything but all i ever get is this message

`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

No matter what I try. I am about to drop WSL forever. Hope someone can help me recover my INNODB Files to a new installation of MAMP?

Comment: Never using WSL1 is a good thing, as it relies on LXSS Manager Service for the emulation of Linux system calls instead of true virtualization.

Comment: @K7AAY I've used WSL1 but not SQL. I don't see how his MySQL problems have anything to do with Virtual Machine of WSL2 versus translation calls of WSL1. After all it was working fine before upgrade to 20.04. When I upgraded my 16.04 to 18.04 from Microsoft store it got fried too. That said I do look forward to WSL2 release and trying it out.

Comment: I have opted to stop using mysql on WSL now. I have moved to MYSQL server for windows. Which i can can connect to with with 127.0.0.1. It seems a little slower. Im still using WSL for apache2, but I am toying with the idea of getting a seperate stand-alone server and just install ubuntu on it.